# aliasing names in one to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I am using some `Message` model with a `content` and `sender` and `receiver`, so I put

```
  attr_accessible :sender_id
  attr_accessible :receiver_id
  attr_accessible  :content

  belongs_to :user
```

in my `User` model

```
has_many :messages, foreign_key: 'sender_id', class_name: "Message"
has_many :pushes, foreign_key: 'receiver_id', class_name: "Message"
```

First, is this a best practice ?

Btw, suppose I have some `message` instance, how can I get in a `rails way` the receiver and the sender instance, without writing `User.find(message.sender_id)` or `` `User.find(message.receiver_id) ``. (Btw, I know I can use some table and use `has_many through` mecanism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user model seems to be setup properly.

Regarding your second question, you can do this:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'User'
end
```

That way, both `message.sender` and `message.receiver` will give you a user object.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

I have this in my current app:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :to, class_name: User
  belongs_to :from, class_name: User
end
```

Given an instance of a Message, I just do, for example:

```
if message.to == current_user
...
```

The relevant part of my User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, foreign_key: :to_id # These are received messages
  has_many :sent_messages, foreign_key: :from_id, class_name: Message
```